Combining p-values from bootstrap iterations
I am trying to model the probability of a mutation with respect to a continuous response variable $x$. I am building a logistic regression model with mutation status of each gene as $y$, and $x$ as a parameter in my regression model. The resulting coefficient represents the log-odds probability increase of a mutation with a unit increase in $x$. I am fitting a separate model for each gene, similar to what is done in DESeq2.
From these models, I can easily compute a p-value.
I am bootstrapping this procedure $n$ times, as I found I was often getting unstable results with small changes in my input data. I want to rank these genes by some metric, to take into account the magnitude of change in mutation probability (coefficient), and the evidence I have that backs this up (standard error).
I could rank the genes according to the log-odds increase in mutation probability, but these do not consider the standard error associated with measurements in $x$. Therefore, I'd like to use a statistic like p-value that does account for that, but I am bootstrapping this whole process and believe I cannot simply average p-values (here).
What can I use to order these genes to get a single ranking across all bootstrap replicates? Would it be appropriate to rank in each individual bootstrap iteration, and then average these rankings?
I am fairly new to statistics, so any reading you can recommend would be really helpful.

I think probably you do not actually want to use the $p$-value from each of your bootstrap regressions, you can run into a lot of problems that way (as it seems you figured out). There are multiple different things you can do other than that, see, e.g., here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83012/how-to-obtain-p-values-of-coefficients-from-bootstrap-regression, or you can maybe check out the boot.pval R package which has some references of potential interest.

@wzbillings Thanks, I’ll have a look at those sources and see if I can figure something appropriate out.
