# Performing an ANOVA on bootstrapped values

Tags: anova, bootstrap

I have a 2 x 2 experimental design and have bootstrapped the distribution of a particular statistic for each cell. Is it possible to perform something akin to an ANOVA on these bootstrapped data such that I can characterize the main effect of each factor and their interaction? My intuition is that simply entering these bootstrapped values into a conventional ANOVA would be incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must perform an ANOVA on each of the bootstrapped datasets. Take the resulting distribution of test statistics and apply appropriate inference. See also: [Computing p-value using bootstrap with R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/computing-p-value-using-bootstrap-with-r/277391#277391)