# SPSS computation of the 2-sided bootstrap p-value

Tags: p-value, spss, bootstrap

In the [SPSS Statistics Algorithm Manual Version 29](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSLVMB_29.0.0/pdf/IBM_SPSS_Statistics_Algorithms.pdf) (p.132 in the pdf) the computation of the two-sided p-value for the bootstrap procedure is described as follows:
[image: bootstrap_p-value]
Sadly, because of different RNGs, I cannot verify the computation via R and have to rely on the manual in order to recreate SPSS's computation.

What is unclear to me is what standard errors are used to compute the test statistics $z_0$ and $z_b^*$.
$SE_b^*$ is never explicitly described in the manual as far as I can tell, but since the manual writes that the standard error is estimated "from the standard error calculated within the procedure" one could interpret this as $SE_b^*$ being the standard error of the *b*th parameter estimate $T_b^*$ of the *b*th bootstrap sample and $SE$ being the standard error for the original parameter estimate $T$, where $SE$ estimated via the bootstrap procedure is (SPSS manual p. 131):
[image: bootstrap_SE]
Does anyone happen to have any knowledge about this particular approach described in SPSS? I know that there is a variety of ways to compute the p-values for bootstrap tests (e.g. see [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20701/computing-p-value-using-bootstrap-with-r)) but I am specifically interested in the SPSS two-sided p-value.