Why could data bootstraping modifiy the slope of a population comming from the same distribution?
Im bootstraping some samples to calculate slopes (with replacement). Once that is done, the slopes that should have the same distribution, do not have the same distribution. To be clear im not asking for debugging the code, but to understand why im introducing a bias.
Here a reproducible code in R:
library(plotly)

N<- 3000
x <- runif(N,0,1)*5
y <- x + rnorm(N, 1, .2)
y2 <- x + rnorm(N, 1, .2)
t.test(y,y2)
dummy <- rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),each = N)
df <- data.frame(x = c(x,x), y = c(y,y2), dummy = dummy)

fig <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_trace(x = df[df$dummy == TRUE,]$x, y = df[df$dummy == TRUE,]$y) %>%
  add_trace(x = df[df$dummy == FALSE,]$x, y= df[df$dummy == FALSE,]$y)
fig

boot_strap <- function(data, n_bootstraps){
  output <- sapply(1:n_bootstraps, function(i){
                      tmp <- data[sample(seq_len(nrow(data)), nrow(data), replace = TRUE),]
                      model <- lm(y ~ x, data = tmp)
                      return(coef(model)[2])
                      })
  return(output)
}

  
for (size in c(1e2, 2e2, 5e2, 1e3, 1e4)){
    sample_1 <- boot_strap(df[df$dummy == TRUE,], size)
    sample_2 <- boot_strap(df[df$dummy == FALSE,], size)   
    print(paste0('Size: ', size,' - Pvalue: ', t.test(sample_1, sample_2)$p.value))
}

fig <- plot_ly() %>%
  add_histogram(sample_1) %>%
  add_histogram(sample_2)
fig

The data:

Here we do not have a difference as is comming from the same population (as shown by the first T-test) what is expected
but in the other hand, the distribution of the slopes are significantly different.

Where is my bias?

Have you tried repeating this with different random seed values to get different random samples? The differences between the slope estimates are numerically very small, with almost all values between 0.99 and 1.01. It's possible that this was just the luck of the draw in the original sampling to get y and y2.

Welcome to Cross Validated. Your R code is not complete, something is missing.

Once the missing end braces } are inserted into the code, it doesn't appear to do what you describe.  Your problem therefore is with the code.  I suggest you test and debug it.

Thanks all for your time. @EdM, yes. I tried and bias is always there. I also modify the code for a full reproduction. I also re tried in a Mac computer, just in case, and same problem..

The issue here is your use of a t-test. That is simply not valid based on bootstrap results. Check the slopes from regression with the original data. The estimated slopes are actually different (of course). The t-test derives the standard error from the standard deviation (here of the bootstrap slope estimates) and from n (here n_bootstraps). However, remember that the standard deviation of the bootstrap slope estimates is an estimate of the standard error of the original slope estimate. The t-test is not testing what you think it tests.

You can simplify your code to N<- 3000; x1 <- rnorm(N, 1, .2); x2 <- rnorm(N, 1, .2); library(boot); b1 <- boot(x1, \(x, i) mean(x[i]), 1e4); b2 <- boot(x2, \(x, i) mean(x[i]), 1e4); t.test(b1$t, b2$t).

@whuber The code is fine.

@Roland Code that produces a result contrary to what its programmer intended might run but scarcely can be called "fine."  But since it looks like you understand what the code does and you have a statistical explanation, I am glad to reopen the question and hope you might elevate your comments to an answer.

@Roland But wouldn't you still expect the t-test on bootstrapped slopes to not detect the difference? The significant result seem robust at different sample sizes of the original simulated datasets (different numbers for N) and different boot strap numbers (different numbers for size). I have been playing around with the code for a bit and I am too struggling to understand why that is the case.

@doubtful_noob I will try to write an answer next week. For now, consider these facts: both samples are from the same population, so we know the true means are equal. However, the sample means are different. The bootstrap means can be biased but in this simulation that bias is very low (you can check). Since OP is using the number of bootstrap iterations in the t-test, it will always produce a significant result. But if you calculate quantiles of the bootstrap resamples, which is a standard approach to derive confidence intervals of the estimate of the population mean, you’ll see that they…

… overlap. If you want to use bootstrap to test H0: mu1=mu2, then you should bootstrap the difference of the means (or slopes in OP’s example) and search this site for how to derive p-values from the bootstrap approach.

@whuber The code implements OP’s algorithm correctly. OP’s algorithm is wrong but that’s not a coding issue.

@Roland Frankly, I have no idea what OP's intended algorithm might be, because it isn't described and the plots aren't even labeled, providing few clues.  I am glad you have been able to figure this all out.

For didactic reasons, I will use bootstrapping the sample mean as an example. All arguments are valid for other statistics (like a regression slope). I will also use the boot package instead of your (correct) manual implementation of the bootstrap.
First, let's remember, what the statistic of the Welch t-test is:
$t = \frac{\bar{x_1} - \bar{x_2}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{s_1}{\sqrt{n_1}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{s_2}{\sqrt{n_2}}\right)^2}}$
where $\frac{s_j}{\sqrt{n_j}}$ are the standard errors of the means. This formula of the standard error is valid for samples from a normal distribution, which is a basic assumption of the t-test.
Looking at the formula of $t$ we can see that if the sample means and standard deviations are kept constant and the sample sizes increase, $t$ increases and consequantly, the p-value decreases. (In fact, analysis of power is based on this.)
Now, what is the purpose of the bootstrap? We use the bootstrap to infer something about the distribution of a statistic derived from a sample, without having to make strong assumptions about the distribution from which the sample was taken (like it is necessary for the t-test). For example, we can use bootstrap to estimate the standard error of the sample mean. A basic property of the bootstrap method is that if we increase the size of the bootstrap resamples, this estimate approaches a fixed value asymptotically (Efron, 1979).
You can derive p-values from the bootstrap (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/277391/11849). However, doing a t-test with the bootstrap resamples as in your example doesn't test $H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2$, i.e., if the original samples are derived from distributions with equal means. It is nonsense, because the result depends on the size of the bootstrap resamples.
Having said all of this, let's look at an example:
set.seed(42) #for reproducibility

x1 <- rnorm(100)
x2 <- rnorm(100)

#t-test
print(t_test <- t.test(x1, x2))
#   Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  x1 and x2
# t = 0.87011, df = 194.18, p-value = 0.3853
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -0.1519980  0.3919951
# sample estimates:
#   mean of x   mean of y 
#  0.03251482 -0.08748371 

The Welch t-test gives a non-significant p-value as expected. The R function helpfully shows the sample means. Obviously, these will always be different for the two samples, even though the samples are from the same distribution. Nevertheless, the sample mean is an estimator of the distribution mean.
m1 <- mean(x1)
m2 <- mean(x2)
se1 <- sd(x1)/sqrt(100)
se2 <- sd(x2)/sqrt(100)

Now, let's bootstrap these means with increasing sizes of the bootstrap resamples:
library(boot)
nboot <- ((1:25) *10)^2
myboots <- lapply(nboot, function(n, x1, x2) {
  cbind(
    boot(x1, function(x, i) mean(x[i]), n)$t, 
    boot(x2, function(x, i) mean(x[i]), n)$t
  )
}, x1 = x1, x2 = x2)

We can now plot the bootstrap means:
bootmeans <- sapply(myboots, function(x) colMeans(x))

matplot(nboot, t(bootmeans), pch = 16, main = "bootstrap means")
legend("center", pch = 16, col = 1:2, legend = c("sample 1", "sample 2"))
abline(h = m1, col = 1)
abline(h = m2, col = 2)


We can nicely see that with increasing bootstrap n the bootstrap means approach the sample means and bias is very low.
The same for the standard deviations, which are an estimate of the standard errors of the means:
bootSE <- sapply(myboots, function(x) apply(x, 2, sd))
matplot(nboot, t(bootSE), pch = 16, main = "bootstrap standard errors")
legend("top", pch = 16, col = 1:2, legend = c("sample 1", "sample 2"))
abline(h = se1, col = 1)
abline(h = se2, col = 2)


We see that they approach values close to the estimates based on the original samples and the assumption of normal distribution. We can also look at t-values:
plot(nboot, (bootmeans[1,] - bootmeans[2,])/sqrt(bootSE[1,]^2 + bootSE[2,]^2), pch = 16, main = "bootstrap t-values")
abline(h = t_test$statistic, col = 1)


Again, these are pretty constant for large bootstrap n and agree quite well with the t-test on the orginal samples.
Now, what went wrong in your approach?
Well, by using the t.test functions with the bootstrap resamples, you have an additional division by the square root of the bootstrap n. I will plot these wrong t-values against the square root of bootstrap n (different x-axis than the other plots).
plot(sqrt(nboot), (bootmeans[1,] - bootmeans[2,])/sqrt(bootSE[1,]^2/nboot + bootSE[2,]^2/nboot), pch = 16, main = "wrong t-values")
legend("bottom", pch = 16, col = 1:2, legend = c("sample 1", "sample 2"))


As you see these t-values will go to infinity if you increase the size of the bootstrap resamples. Consequently, p-values will approach zero.
Finally, your last plot shows strongly overlapping histograms. The plot doesn't show a significant difference.

Thanks for your time Roland!
